# Use all hosts completed by zsh for cssh

Tags: zsh, wildcards, autocomplete, cluster-ssh

Is there any possibility to use all completed hosts with cssh?

E.g: `cssh www*`

This should establish three connections to `www1`, `www2`, `www3`

If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after www I get all three possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the *menu-select* completion. At the very least:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=0
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

But see `compinstall` to better tailor it to your taste (like with colours, approximators, descriptions, headers...).

You can type:

```
cssh wwwTabTabAlt+AAlt+A...
```

The first <kbd>Tab</kbd> lists the completions (if there's more than one), the second <kbd>Tab</kbd> starts to select the first one. If you typed <kbd>Tab</kbd> again (though you could also use arrow keys) you could use the next available completion *instead*. But if you type <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> (for *AND*) instead, it accepts the current completion (inserts it at the prompt) and completes again for the next word at the next completion suggestion.

So you can type <kbd>Alt+A</kbd> as many times as there are completions you want to insert.

See

```
info zsh menu-select
```

for details.

To insert all the possible completions, see [this SO answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/28080457)